# IP-driven CMS behavior

Tags: articles, configuration

As part of an intranet project, I'd like to know whether a CMS behavior can be linked to a range of client IP addresses.

The intranet contents and menus would change depending on the range of IP address the server is accessed from. Are there existing modules that will allow this IP-driven behavior?

If possible, I'd like to run the intranet on Joomla.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look also to Nonumbers Extensions: [Advanced Module Manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager) and [Advanced Template Manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager).

They provide many handy tools where you can customize the way sections of your website will behave.

### #Update

To extend a bit my initial answer, If I would look for accuracy inside the intranet, I wouldn't count on the IP's. Probably the intranet would require some kind of login for the users, so I would use profiles and categories/groupings. Then I would configure the "CMS behavior" based on that users data.

And yes, you definitely can build an intranet with Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there's no built in way to do this, though I tinkered with doing it by modifying an existing extension called [Simple Mobile Detection](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display/21806) that specified different templates for different devices.  Altering the code to do the same thing based on the IP address would be quite easy if you're a programmer

Answer (score 1):

For an Intranet project, seems rather strange that you want to associate users with a specific IP range. What if that changes? Don't you have any other characteristics you can use?

How about authenticating the users? Single Signon using perhaps LDAP (which is available as a plugin), why not use the build in ACL system.

If they are truly guests with no name, no face, I can imagine the following architecture:

- create a guest account with basically no permissions.
- authenticate any guest in the background via an authentication plugin. In the authentication plugin you can check the IP.
- create a view level / access group for that guest user and use the ACL to assign menu items and content.

Even if you don't authenticate users, I would still look into a solution based on the Joomla ACL.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite IP-based trigger is [MetaMod .](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/3391?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo3OiJtZXRhbW9kIjtpOjE7czo4OiJtZXRhbW9kZSI7fQ==) Beyond the application you're intending in controlling content based on IP range, it can also present content in a variety of ways based on user location, time of day, etc.  While this doesn't all apply to your project, I find it to be the best investment for someone who will want a lot of features for a modest amount of money.  Someone who may make a new website in the future and use it for other applications also.